# React nested routes for every folder

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, react-router, react-router-dom, directory-structure

I need help to understand how routing works in React.
Currently all my routes are defined in App.js file like this :

```
function App() {
    return (
    <Fragment>
      <div id="sys_slot">
        <Routes>
          <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}/>
          <Route path="/dashboard/*" element={<Dashboard />} />
          <Route path="/wordy/*" element={<Wordy />} />
          <Route path="/wordy/learn" element={<LearnWindow />} />
          <Route path="/wordy/learn/rumbo" element={<SomeOtherComponent />} />
          <Route path="/wordy/rev" element={<RevWindow />} />
          <Route path="/cetrec/*" element={<Cetrec />} />
        </Routes>
      </div>
      <BottomNav />
    </Fragment>
    );
}
```

How can I segregate these nested routes (/wordmaster/anything_here/anything_here_again) into their component folders?

Also, what exactly does this Routes tag do, does it play any role in rendering of the component?

Can I use it anywhere in the return code and can I use it(call a Link to path) before these Routes are defined?

I'm using latest RRD version.

Thank you very much for any guidance that you can provide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I segregate these nested routes
> (`"/wordmaster/anything_here/anything_here_again"`) into their component
> folders?

You can move these routes into the component you want to render them. They would be rendered again into a `Routes` component.

Example:

App - renders the base/root routes, wildcard `*` appended to route paths so sub-routes can be matched.

```
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="/dashboard/*" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="/wordy/*" element={<Wordy />} />
  <Route path="/cetrec/*" element={<Cetrec />} />
</Routes>
```

Wordy - Renders relative links and paths.

```
<ul>
  <li>
    <Link to="learn">Learn</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="learn/rumbo">Rumbo</Link>
  </li>
  <li>
    <Link to="rev">Rev</Link>
  </li>
</ul>
<Routes>
  <Route path="learn" element={<LearnWindow />} />
  <Route path="learn/rumbo" element={<SomeOtherComponent />} />
  <Route path="rev" element={<RevWindow />} />
</Routes>
```

[image: Edit react-nested-routes-for-every-folder]

You can keep breaking the routes down as granularly as you need.

> Also, what exactly does this Routes tag do, does it play any role in
> rendering of the component?

It ***does*** play a role in the rendering of the component. It's the component that takes the children routes, computes the best match, and renders it.

[`Routes` source](https://github.com/remix-run/react-router/blob/main/packages/react-router/lib/components.tsx#L403-L414)

> ```
> /**
>  * A container for a nested tree of <Route> elements that renders the branch
>  * that best matches the current location.
>  *
>  * @see https://reactrouter.com/components/routes
>  */
> export function Routes({
>   children,
>   location,
> }: RoutesProps): React.ReactElement | null {
>   return useRoutes(createRoutesFromChildren(children), location);
> }
> ```

> Can I use it anywhere in the return code and can I use it(call a Link
> to path) before these Routes are defined?

Use the `Routes` component anywhere you are rendering a `Route` component. The only valid children of `Routes` is `Route` and `React.Fragment`, and all `Route` components can ***only*** be a child of the `Routes` component or another `Route` (*in the case of nesting routes*). Links and routes can be declared independently of each other, but it doesn't make much sense to link to routes that don't exist.

Comment: Thank you very much. This gave me the answer for how I needed to add '/*' after every link address if I ever want to further go deep into that url path. Just like how I went for this in order to nest url in "learn" for "rumbo". `<Route path="learn/*" element={<LearnWindow />} />`